# Reserve php foreach. array_reverse doesn't works

Tags: php

Using php I try to reserve the result of a foreach cycle, this is the var_dump of the object:

```
 object(ProcessWire\PadNoteArray)#996 (2) {
     ["count"]=> int(3)
     ["items"]=> array(3) {
         [0]=> string(9) "PadNote-1"
         [1]=> string(9) "PadNote-2"
         [2]=> string(9) "PadNote-3"
     }
    }
```

**How do I reverse the order of items?**

**array_reverse($notes, true) doesn't works**

To arrive to have this:

```
$notes = $ordine->pad_order_notes;

foreach ($notes as $notee){
  echo $notee
}

[2]=> string(9) "PadNote-3"
[1]=> string(9) "PadNote-2"
[0]=> string(9) "PadNote-1"
```

Thank you

Comment: Does the class have a method to get the list of items? You would need to reverse this list.

Comment: *doesn't works*, what's that mean? your object has `items`, it should probably be `foreach (array_reverse($notes->notes)...`

Comment: Are you sure `array_reverse()` isn't working? Note that it returns a new array (not like `sort()` that works on the original array)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone give me back a null value

Comment: What does `$notes =  array_reverse($ordine->pad_order_notes, true);` do?

Comment: @michel yes I did give me null

Comment: @NigelRen yes I need to reverse the items list. I don't know if there are a method to call the class items.

Comment: So is it `pad_order_notes` or `items`? Make sure you use __correct variable\property__

Comment: @u_mulder the foreach give me the `items` data that I have to print in reverse mode.

Comment: I need to revers the foreach in the way I have 
`"PadNote-3"
"PadNote-2"
"PadNote-1"`

Comment: You have `items` property in `var_dump`. __How__ is `items` related to `pad_order_notes`?

Comment: @u_mulder I make `var_dump($notes)`; or did you want know how the `pad_order_note` are build?

Comment: And that's more clear. If `notes` is an object which have `items` property, then something like `$notes->items` should be reversed.

Comment: So, this still can be closed as dupe, because you apply `array_reverse` to incorrect data\property\variable.

Comment: @u_mulder yes I understend, but here there is another problem, I can't access to `$notes->items`

Comment: Why? You see error or what? Check class definition, maybe there's a getter, like `getItems`

Comment: @u_mulder, yes give me this error: `Error: Exception: Class 'PadNoteArray' doesn't yet implement method 'makeBlankItem()' and it needs to`